# KeyDb replica master is connected, but not working

Tags: caching, replication, keydb

I want to create an active-active replication for keydb, I used the official docs https://docs.keydb.dev/docs/active-rep/ , however, I'm not getting the expected results, even though I'm not getting errors.

```bash
Config A:
port 6379
requirepass mypassword123
masterauth mypassword123
active-replica yes
replicaof 10.0.11.205 6379
```

and on the other side

```bash
Config B:
port 6379
requirepass mypassword123
masterauth mypassword123
active-replica yes
replicaof 10.0.11.208 6379
```

Comment: Please common reproduceable issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hossam could you please share the result of `systemctl status keydb.service`.

1. system start the commands include the following:

> systemctl start keydb.service

2. Please you share the keydb logs, which are  path:  `/var/log/keydb/keydb-server.log` after looking into it work according the replication.
3. Please test with `/usr/bin/keydb-server /etc/keydb/keydb.conf`